# How ot display a Tilemap in Game Boy

Tags: c, gameboy, retro-computing, gbdk

I am trying to display this image with Game Boy Developer Kit and i don't see it displayed when i run the emulator

[image]

The code i use is this one

```
void displayDodge(){
int nbTiles = (160 * 144) / 8;
int i,j;
SPRITES_8x8;
j = 0;
set_sprite_data(0, nbTiles, gbpic_dat);
    for (i=0; i+=8; i<=nbTiles){
        set_sprite_tile(j, j);
        move_sprite(j, i, 75);
        j++;
    };
SHOW_SPRITES;
}
```

I've created a gist for the same project [here](https://gist.github.com/thefailtheory/bb6e88343d658901f818f025217eedfc)

Comment: It seems i must wait for vblank to access oam. Also i need to enable the OBJ flag on LCD CTRL register because i am rendering more sprites

Comment: You can do this either at VBlank or during display redraw